# If/ else statement to set cookie

Tags: php, cookies, if-statement

I am trying to track lead sources via my paid advertising methods. To do so I have created a URL as follows: http://www.student-tutor.com/lp/satbook.php?source=245

I would like for the first time the user comes to that page via a paid source that has ?source= for it to be saved as a cookie. That way if/when they fill out a web form the hidden field will be populated with their original referrer.

Couple questions:

A) How do I go about setting the cookie? Currently this is what I have but doesn't seem to be working. I figured if cookie was set then it would set another cookie leadsource2 to the value. If it wasn't set it would set the leadsource to the correct value. This does not seem to be working.

```
<?php 
$value = $_GET['source']
if(isset($_COOKIE['leadsource']))
setcookie("leadsource2","$value"); 
else
setcookie("leadsource","$value");
?>
```

After this occurs this will check to see if the cookie is set or not. If it is it will get the source.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['leadsource']))
$_COOKIE['leadsource2']= $_GET['source'];  
else
$_COOKIE['leadsource']= $_GET['source'];
?>
```

Finally it will post the original referrer in the hidden field.

```
<input name="inf_field_LeadSourceId" type="hidden" value=" <?= $_COOKIE ['leadsource'] ?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A. this is pointless: `"$value"` Just do `$value`. B. You can't check cookies on the same page you set them, so if that check is on the same page, it will always fail. C. I don't think your checking code does anything like what you think it does.

Comment: You need to redirect before you can set a cookie because they are set through a http request